# Android: GridView with images, how set dynamic size and improve performance

Tags: android, image, gallery, adapter

I want to do an image manager that allows me to add or delete some photos.
I don't wanna use external libraries, if possible. Now I tried to do and adapter for the GridView that shows some pictues, taken from the user using his camera, and I've got some questions:

1. I wanna show 3 images for each row, how can I do that? (now I set the size with imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);)
2. Performance isn't really good, how can I improve it? Because theorically I should put a big number of pictures.

Here is my adapter:

```
public class CustomGalleryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private List<String> resources;

// Constructor
public CustomGalleryAdapter(Context context, List<String> resources){
    super();

    this.context = context;
    this.resources = resources;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return resources.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return resources.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // Crea un ImageView
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);

    // Carica un file dal path dato
    File imgFile = new  File(resources.get(position));

    // Se l'immagine esiste
    if(imgFile.exists()){

        // Decodifica il Bitmap
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

        // Setta il bitmap
        imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
    }

    // Setta le proprietà dell'immagine
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    GridView.LayoutParams layoutParams = new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 150);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    // Ritorna l'immagine
    return imageView;
} 
}
```

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" > 
</GridView>
```

**EDIT:**
I tried to modify, added convertView check and ViewHolder, but I've no idea how to add LruCache support. Help is very much appreciated!

getView method:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {

        Log.d("IMAGES","convertView = null");
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.cell_image, null);      
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cellImage);   
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }           

    Log.d("IMAGES","decoding...");

    // Decodifica il Bitmap
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(resources.get(position));

    // Setta il bitmap
    holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

    return convertView;
}
```

ViewHolder:

```
class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
}
```

cell_image:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/cellImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" >

</ImageView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 File imgFile = new  File(resources.get(position));

    // Se l'immagine esiste
    if(imgFile.exists()){

        // Decodifica il Bitmap
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

        // Setta il bitmap
        imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

That's the root of all evil. OK, i am exaggerating, but this is bad : you are instanciating a new File and decoding it each time getView is called (and it can be called a lot). So this can't lead to good performances.
Why ?
This code runs in the main thread, the one that handles the UI. So you can't do heavy work there unless you want to freeze the UI. This is especially true for methods that handles views such as getView, they are critical to the UI.
And you are decoding bitmaps and reading from the disk there.

You should have a look at how good list/gridView libraries handle this. You have to implement the ConvertView and ViewHandler design patterns in order to work efficiently with getView.
Moreover, you will need to implement your own loader that handles your files at two levels : a lruCache in your memory and fetching them from the disk if they are not in the cache.
Once these 3 things will be implemented, you should have very smooth performances in your list. The listview and 'displaying bitmaps efficiently' lessons on the official Android dev website provide good starting point on these topics.

---

Edit : about the LruCache. The Least Recently Used cache is a cache that will automatically delete its least used entry when it becomes too big (which is very handy in order to do not take too much memory). Android already provides one, it is even part of the support library `android.support.v4.util.LruCache`.
What you want to do is instead of directly read the file and display your bitmap in getView, call a ImageLoader that will do this for you.
The implementation of the loader is up to you. Basically you will have to be able to call it with the address of the image. First it will check if it is already in the memory (it is tremendously faster to read from memory than from the disk) if it is there, display it directly.
If not, you need to work in another thread . Everything that involves either heavy computation, the disk or networking needs to be made outside of the main thread in order to preserve its performances. In the other thread (either with an AsyncTask or a ThreadPool) you will read the file from the disk, put it in the cache and display it back in the main thread.
The official doc already have details on how to work with Lrucache :
https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html
and on how to process bitmaps off the main thread :
https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html
so I won't detail it here.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the first time I'm doing a gallery, your post is a very helpful lineguide. Now I will try, if I have some troubles I'm going to post again

Comment: Glad to hear it. I won't provide the code on how to do this because it would be a bit too long for a stackoverflow answer, but I have provided links that should help you. You can also have a look at the smoothie library on github to see how it handles this (it is a library dedicated to smooth listviews).  For the number of images on a row, this is the android:numColumns attribute that you want to modify.

Comment: I will take care of your answer for future projects, unfortunately I had a very short deadline so I had to use an existing library, but I choose yours as best answer because it's very clear. Thanks again!